# Ionic - Make the windows app run at fullscreen

Tags: windows, uwp, win-universal-app, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

Is it possible to build the windows desktop app at fullscreen? 'Cause initially when I run my app, the size is at 1200x900.

In my config.xml I have this `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />`

I also have this code based on my research from `cordova-plugin-statusbar` :

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  StatusBar.hide();
});
```

But I have no luck in running the app at fullscreen for Windows. I have found a solution but only for android:

```
if (this.platform.is("android")) {
    this.androidFullScreen.isImmersiveModeSupported().then(
      () => this.androidFullScreen.immersiveMode()
    ).catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code , add in **page.ts** file

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
}// where you want full screen

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
}// where you want normal screen
```